# How do I change the color of the screen that is displayed before the login screen?

Tags: boot, customization

How do I change the color that the system displays just before the login screen is displayed?

Here is the boot sequence on my machine in the order that things are displayed:

1. The BIOS screen is flashed.
2. A Black screen is displayed for a few seconds.
3. My Plymouth splash screen is displayed.
4. **Purple screen is displayed for a few seconds** (This is what I want to change).
5. Finally, the login screen is displayed.

Please let me know if you require any additional information while addressing this problem and as always, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open with root privileges `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script` file, find and edit as you wish these lines:

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.16, 0.00, 0.12);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.16, 0.00, 0.12);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
```

For example `(0.0, 0.00, 0.0)` in both cases will give you a black screen.

After you saved the file, run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer Radu. However, this did not solve my problem. I did as you instructed and then ran sudo update-initramfs -u but there was no noticeable difference after the change to the file.

Comment: @JakeNewkirk Do you use some video proprietary drivers?

Comment: No sir, I don't. I checked by going into the Ubuntu Software center-->Edit-->Software Sources and then clicking on the "Additional Drivers" tab. There are none listed in the window and it also states at the bottom of the window, "No proprietary drivers are in use." I'm not sure if this is useful information but I'm not using the default splash screen. I'm using Solar plymouth.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get rid of the ugly purple color that flashes right before the login screen.

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type or copy and paste this in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_unity greeter.gschema.override
   ```
3. An empty file will appear. Don't be scared.

   Just copy and paste this into it:

   ```
   [com.canonical.unity-greeter]
   background-color = "#000000"
   ```

You can choose whatever color you like to enter in the same format shown here

(`#000000`). `#000000` will display the color black instead of that God-awful purple color.

4. Click save and close the file.
5. Type or copy and paste this into the terminal:

   ```
   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
6. Restart your computer.